# Font positioning error relating to either font-size or font encoding

Tags: font-size, webfonts, css, google-webfonts

I've run into a problem where the glyphs are positioned as I expect when I specify `line height:1` UNTIL the font-size became greater than 255px. Set the font-size to 256 and bam, the glyphs change position dramatically and become too high on the line.

I'm using Google Web fonts to bring in Josefin Sans - http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Josefin+Sans

Edit: I'm using Chrome on Fedora, not one of those cool machines with market share and funding

Simplified fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/jBAnc/

Edit: The fiddle isn't showing the code for me. If you click on "Bacon", it'll toggle between 255 and 256, causing it to bounce back and forth (at least for me).

I don't encounter this problem when the font is a basic web-safe font such as Arial, so I assume it has something to do with the google Web-font. Is this a problem with the font's encoding, possibly the program the font was created with (255 seems significant)?

[image: this is a screenshot of my original problem]

Comment: For me in Google Chrome, the fiddle works just fine. Plus, why would you want such a big font size? Just curious.

Comment: Big text is for titles in a presentation. You were clicking the bacon without the font moving up and down?

Comment: Not seeing any major jump between 255/256 on my end using that jsfiddle (tested: Chrome 23.0.1271.97, Safari (PC) 5.1.7, FF 17.0.1, and IE 9)

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting inconsistent line-height/spacing issues with this font. I'm beginning to suspect that it's a problem with the construction of Josefin Sans itself.

EDIT: after a little more Googlizing, it appears the issue is not so much the font itself, but the Google Webfont API.

http://webdesignandsuch.com/fix-fonts-that-dont-work-with-google-font-api-in-internet-explorer-or-chrome-with-font-face/

Short answer: Download and host the font yourself and you should have no issues.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong at all. You're just expecting all fonts to have the same x-height, descender/extender-heights, and they just don't (9 times out of 10).

The following fiddle illustrates the differences between 4 fonts (3 being very common fonts found on Macs, PCs, etc). And Josefin Sans is in the house as well.

Pay particular attention to the differences in:

- the top spacing between the capital Q and its parent's border
- the various heights of the Xx (especially, the lower-case vs capital)
- descender of the lower-case G (some actually come out of their
  parent)

_http://jsfiddle.net/suK2U/

[image]

To answer your question about 255/256px, I'd venture to say that you just happened upon a 'sweet-spot' between your container and its parent. At 256, it starts colliding (and margins start to collapse, or the like).

Comment: I'm not expecting fonts to have the same heights at all. This one is drastically changing at that breakpoint. Also, when I open your fiddle, those fonts x-heights aren't displaying for me as they are in your image. I'm using Chrome on a slightly older version of Fedora, so maybe the problem lays there, somehow.

Comment: Just to check, Josefin Sans for you has space for the descenders, the way my 256px version looks right? I imagine that's how it's supposed to look, I'm just not sure why it shifts for me.